# maven - how to use local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am newbie to maven. I have few questions on it.

I have to build a webapp and prepare a war out of it. I have put my web application under `..\src\main\webapp`. And all classes of it, which were under web-inf\classes, i have copied to `..\src\main\java.` And i have put pom.xml in the root directory.
I have numerous jars in web-inf\lib folder, on which my compilation of classes depends on. I want to add all those to my local repository. My local repository is default folder, which i have not changed in settings.xml. So, how do i put all these jars to my local repository? Just copying jars to local repository folder is not working.

Should i create a folder for each jar as per its groupid? Am i doing things correctly? Or i am missing something?

Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy to maven local repository you can use an install plugin:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

Comment: Actually, better link would be http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html - simpler and more to the point (question specifies it's just default local repository)

Comment: To install a JAR in the local repository use the following command: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging> So it means copying the jar to local repository. Is it?

Comment: This command will do it correctly for you, but yeah, that is basically what will happen.

Comment: Thanks @Tarlog. But do i do this for each and every jar file?

Comment: What is the source of these jar files? Aren't they already deployed to some remote repository? Or maybe you are building them as part of some other project locally?
If yes, it's quite easy to make Maven deploy them. Otherwise, you'll need to deploy every and every jar.

Comment: @Tarlog Thanks! I am able to install jars to my local repository using the command mvn install:install-file, which can be used by my web app to build :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confused enough. Firstly try to explain in a better way how to are doing? 
If you are trying to add maven nature at your project (like I think) there are something to review.

I'm not able to understand when you say:

> And all classes of it, which were under web-inf\classes, i have copied to ..\src\main\java

Usually in web-inf/classes there are the .class files, while in src/main/java there must be the source files. And this is an strange thing

Finally fon dependencies copy you have to just configure maven correctly and add all jar like project's dependencies. Then when you try to install you application maven will download the jars file in your folder

Comment: I meant my product code is checked in an web app structure. So my web-inf\classes has java files. Those files i have placed in the ..\src\main\java for my maven build. And i am not supposed to use dependency in pom.xml, i will have to use repository. So, i want to know how to place libraries in local repository, which can be used by my build. I have more than 40 jars to be placed in repository.

Comment: @Anita "And i am not supposed to use dependency in pom.xml, i will have to use repository" sounds really fishy. Only thing pom.xml will change is to download dependencies from the internet to your local repository. Unless you have 40 jars that are not in global maven repositories... Also, in standard web app structure in web-inf\classes there are .class files, not .java. That's a difference.

Comment: @Skizzo sorry if my understanding on maven is incorrect as i am very new to it. My checked in code as .java files. I will have to compile all those files to .class files and prepare war out of it using maven. So is there a way i can include all those dependent jars for maven build. I read about dependency tag of pom.xml, it requires the groupid, version everything to be mentioned in pom.xml, which is very tedious to me to add all 40+ jars that way. And i will have to have those jars in global maven repositories.

Comment: So my question is ; is there a way to add those myself to local repository and make maven build use it?

Comment: @Anita  Yes, The other way is to install manually your jar files in local repository, but this is strange because to start a build lifecycle to maven you must have them declared in your pom